# Restrict Places Autocomplete API to cities of specific country android

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

I am using `PlaceAutocompleteApi` from Play Services, what I want to do is restrict auto-complete to specific country & city only. Eg. All cities from lets say India only. I am using `AutocompleteFilter` to do so but I don't know where to specify country that I want to restrict.

Here is my code

```
        List<Integer> autocompleteFilter = new ArrayList<>();
//        autocompleteFilter.add(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY);
//        autocompleteFilter.add(Place.TYPE_LOCALITY);


        mAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(mContext,R.layout.layout_location_text,
                mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS, AutocompleteFilter.create(autocompleteFilter));
        mTxtLocation.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mTxtLocation.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
```

any thoughts on this?

Comment: have you seen my answer ? where have you reached with this ?

Answer (score 8):

The way to do that is to add the country as the `components` parameter to the web service URL:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
sb.append("&components=country:in");
```

For cities you can use either the `administrative_area_level_3` tag:

```
sb.append("&components=administrative_area_level_3:bengaluru");
```

or alternatively the `locality` tag:

```
sb.append("&components=locality:redmond");
```

**References:**

**1.** [**Geocoding API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start).

**2.** [**Address Types and Component Types**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types).

**3.** [**Google Place API Autocomplete Service in Android Application**](http://codetheory.in/google-place-api-autocomplete-service-in-android-application/).

Comment: thanks, can you suggest using play services api. Not by rest api.

Comment: @3287204 any possibility to get results from only city like Chennai address only

Comment: this doesn't use, as the question says, the PlaceAutocompleteApi

Comment: @AlbertoM: The Play Services API calls keep changing, whereas the API approach has remained more or less the same as before, which is why I have answered as I have. I am still using this approach two years later.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I was using your same approach until I found out about the Places API (same thing that OP was asking). It's valid and it works, but it doesn't answer his/my question IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a workaround (hack if you will) that I used. It utilizes (exploits) the fact that when converted to string, each response item is a comma separated string. Do the following steps before returning the result to `getFilter()`.

1. Get the suggestions into an `ArrayList`, call it `returnedResults`.
2. Now traverse over `returnedResults` and in each iteration get each prediction into a string array using `returnedResults.get(i).getFullText(xxx).toString().split(",")`.
3. If the last element of this array is your country's name, insert it in a separate `ArrayList` variable, let's call it `myResult`.
4. return `myResult`.

The reason for using separate variables is because you might not be able to manipulate the original response list so easily. This approach works like a charm!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice idea. But how to deal with that fact that for different locales country will be probably written in a different way?

Comment: @Leo there's an option (query parameter) for the language in which you want the response

Comment: Abhishek Patel thank you! I can not set locale in query, as settled with the last GoogleApiClient. But I just created the list of needed countries in a few languages and check whether getFullText contains any of them before adding prediction. This significantly improved suggestions. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

Filter results by country

```
// Create Filter
AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
    .setCountry("AU")
    .build();
// Attach to autocomplete fragment / widget
autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val sb = StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON)
            sb.append("?key=$API_KEY")
            sb.append("&types=establishment")
            sb.append("&location=$locationLat,$LocationLng")
            sb.append("&radius=50000&strictbounds")
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"))
```

**This api will restrict the search to area.**