# How to get Country Specific Results in Google Places API for AutocompletePredictions in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to get Search Results for a Specific Country. I have tried for setting Latitude and Longitude, but it may include other countries' results near to required Country!

I have seen other questions which suggest to pass `&components=country:COUNTRY_NAME` in the request URL(I have seen it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30909630/5211482)). But I want to pass request from Google Places API.

I'm using following method:

> Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient,
>   constraint.toString(), mBounds, mPlaceFilter);

But I couldn't find any way to pass a country name for getting result for the specific country. (I have tried passing country name in the Request URL and it is working.) But how to achieve the same by using `Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions()` method?

Or is there any other way to achieve this without sending country name in the Request URL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder().
                    setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY).setCountry("IN").build();

Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                            .setFilter(typeFilter)
                            .build(this);
```

Comment: setCountry is working. Only thing that it requires com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1. Check https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Answer (score 5):

> The `(regions)` type collection instructs the Places service to return
>   any result matching the following types:
>
> - locality
> - sublocality
> - postal_code
> - country
> - administrative_area_level_1
> - administrative_area_level_2
>
> **The (regions) type collection is not supported in [Google Places API for Android.](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start)**

Reference from : Official Guide of [Google Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types).

If you want to implement this,

- Use LatLng bounds with your country's specific area specified by latitude and longitude to restrict the results.
- You can also use the Google Places [Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/).

**Sample:** For restricting your country via Web Service, showing results of country India.

URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=AIzaSyCkvow9LlFNOywy8lzaekn-xROBZRsSFvU&input=a&types=(cities)&components=country:ind

**Note:** *If you want to apply the `country` filter to Google Places API, unfortunately you have to use WebService as of now there is no Filter/Method available in Android API to restrict by country(excluding LatLng Bounds).*

Comment: How can apply a city filter?

Answer (score 2):

With javascript you may use Component restrictions like below code, try to rewrite for Android:

```
var options = {
    // bounds : boundsByCity,
     types: ["geocode"],
     componentRestrictions: { country: "IN" } 
};

//Create the search box and link it to the UI element
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var temp = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide information to implement this in android. Please post the code related to android as this question mentions it.

Comment: @those who upvoted this answer: how did you implemented it in java?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do this.

1. Use latLng bounds for your country to restrict the results.(but this would be rectangular bounds. so the restriction would be approximate).

2 You should use the web service api. it works with android also.

http://codetheory.in/google-place-api-autocomplete-service-in-android-application/

You could use address types and address components to restrict the results using this API in the way you desire:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types

Comment: Hi @shreyas, I have tried both. But I want to pass it from Google API. I want it because I want to show user quick response in AutoCompleteTextView while in JSON first I need to find the data from JSON and then show it as list. So better option for me is to use Google API. So is there any way to do it without using Web Services?